# How do I create a program for a friend without him having to download any of the external libraries?

Tags: python, executable

I am trying to create a program for a friend which requires I import libraries such as:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
```

These required me to install things to my computer in order to run the py file, but I am trying to avoid my friend having to do this. Is there any way that this can be done? I'm sure there is a simple method and just have never come across it before, thank you!

I've tried setting up a local environment or creating an executable file using PyInstaller. Are these effective options? Would I simply be able to create a virtualenv and send it over with the project file? How would that work?

Comment: Lots of choices -- pyinstaller is one, Docker is another, distributing a virtual machine image (for tools like VMware Player) is a third. "Effective" depends on details outside the scope of the question; leaving those details out makes the question too broad and opinion-based to be on-topic. (All of these approaches have limitations; we'd need to get into details of your friend's deployment environment, which (if any) other libraries are used by your code, whether it needs access to files or such on the host, &c to determine which of those limitations are applicable to you)

Comment: It depends on why your friend cannot install external libraries. If you just don't want him to spend time setting up his environment and he has some technical knowledge, then Docker. If he knows Python, then maybe just add requirements.txt to your project? If he is not a technical person at all, use PyInstaller

Comment: ...that said, "use PyInstaller" works a lot more reliably if both you and your friend are on the same OS release; if you're not, it can get... finicky, particularly when you have different DLLs installed &c and your Python code depends on C modules that use 'em.

Comment: Honestly, when I need to write software to be run by Joe Random User on Windows, _I don't use CPython at all_; the dotnet ecosystem is a lot more stable there, making [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/) (or another language of your choice that compiles to dotnet assemblies) a better choice.

Comment: What does the program do?

Comment: (whereas when I write software for people who _aren't_ on Windows, I package it with [Nix](https://nixos.org/); it's tooling for technical audiences, sure, but it does a better job of reproducibility than almost anything else out there).